# Built-in microphone not detected on Ubuntu 22.04 Alienware m17

Tags: 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I cannot use my built-in microphone since it seems to be not detected by the system. Here is a screenshot of the
[sound tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVN1U.png) from the settings panel: the "Input Device" control is disabled.

[image: sound tab]

What should I check?

Here some info about my system obtained with alsa-info:

```
!!Script ran on: Fri May 26 09:50:55 UTC 2023


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS" PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Alienware
Product Name:      Alienware m17 R5 AMD
Product Version:   1.4.3
Firmware Version:  1.4.3
System SKU:        0B5B
Board Vendor:      Alienware
Board Name:        0G8CH8


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/AMDI0007:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/AMDI0010:03/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/AMDI0030:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/AMDI0052:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/DELL0B5B:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/DELLABCE:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:01/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:02/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:03/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:04/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:08/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:09/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0b/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0e/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0f/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:10/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:11/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:12/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:16/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXVIDEO:01/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0101:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/NVDA0820:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/NXP8013:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0A:00/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C50:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/USBC000:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:12/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:13/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:16/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:19/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:1a/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:1b/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:1c/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:26/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:31/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:32/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:35/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:36/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:3b/status   15


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.15.0-52-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.15.0-52-generic
Library version:    1.2.6.1
Utilities version:  1.2.6


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel (card 0)
snd_hda_intel (card 1)
snd_hda_intel (card 2)


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

PipeWire:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pipewire)
      Running - Yes

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0x79000000 irq 66
 1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0x798c8000 irq 90
 2 [Generic_1      ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0x798c0000 irq 91


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:2288] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0000]
34:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1640]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1640]
34:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: Dell Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1028:0b5b]


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    dmic_detect : Y
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    pm_blacklist : Y
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 1
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : -1
    snoop : -1

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    dmic_detect : Y
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    pm_blacklist : Y
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 1
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : -1
    snoop : -1

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    dmic_detect : Y
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    pm_blacklist : Y
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 1
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : -1
    snoop : -1
   

!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 15 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/controlC2
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 14 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/hwC2D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/pcmC0D9p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 12 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/pcmC2D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 11 May 26 11:43 /dev/snd/pcmC2D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 13 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/pcmC2D2c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 May 26 11:25 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 100 May 26 11:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 380 May 26 11:25 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 May 26 11:25 pci-0000:01:00.1 -> ../controlC0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 May 26 11:25 pci-0000:34:00.1 -> ../controlC1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 May 26 11:25 pci-0000:34:00.6 -> ../controlC2


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC3254 Analog [ALC3254 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC3254 Analog [ALC3254 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 2: ALC3254 Alt Analog [ALC3254 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card NVidia

Card sysdefault:0 'NVidia'/'HDA NVidia at 0x79000000 irq 66'
  Mixer name    : 'Nvidia GPU 9d HDMI/DP'
  Components    : 'HDA:10de009d,10280b5c,00100100'
  Controls      : 28
  Simple ctrls  : 4
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',3
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]

!!-------Mixer controls for card Generic

Card sysdefault:1 'Generic'/'HD-Audio Generic at 0x798c8000 irq 90'
  Mixer name    : 'ATI R6xx HDMI'
  Components    : 'HDA:1002aa01,00aa0100,00100800'
  Controls      : 7
  Simple ctrls  : 1
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]

!!-------Mixer controls for card Generic_1

Card sysdefault:2 'Generic_1'/'HD-Audio Generic at 0x798c0000 irq 91'
  Mixer name    : 'Realtek ALC3254'
  Components    : 'HDA:10ec0295,10280b5b,00100002'
  Controls      : 22
  Simple ctrls  : 11
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 1 [33%] [10.00dB]
  Front Right: 1 [33%] [10.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-51.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 39 [62%] [12.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 39 [62%] [12.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',1
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 38 [60%] [11.25dB] [off]
  Front Right: Capture 38 [60%] [11.25dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Disabled'
Simple mixer control 'Headset Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',0
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Headset Mic' 'Headphone Mic'
  Item0: 'Headphone Mic'
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',1
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Headset Mic' 'Headphone Mic'
  Item0: 'Headphone Mic'

!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

ac97_bus
aesni_intel
af_alg
algif_hash
algif_skcipher
alienware_wmi
amd_pmc
amdgpu
autofs4
binfmt_misc
bluetooth
bnep
br_netfilter
bridge
btbcm
btintel
btrtl
btusb
ccm
ccp
cec
cfg80211
cmac
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
dcdbas
dell_rbtn
dell_wmi_descriptor
drm
drm_kms_helper
drm_ttm_helper
ecc
ecdh_generic
edac_mce_amd
efi_pstore
fb_sys_fops
ghash_clmulni_intel
gpu_sched
hid
hid_generic
hid_multitouch
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_hid
i2c_hid_acpi
i2c_piix4
input_leds
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
iommu_v2
ip_tables
joydev
k10temp
kvm
kvm_amd
ledtrig_audio
libarc4
libcrc32c
llc
lp
mac80211
mac_hid
mc
msr
mt76
mt76_connac_lib
mt7921e
nf_conntrack
nf_conntrack_netlink
nf_defrag_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv6
nf_nat
nf_tables
nfnetlink
nft_chain_nat
nft_compat
nft_counter
nls_iso8859_1
nvidia
nvidia_drm
nvidia_modeset
nvidia_uvm
nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight
nvme
nvme_core
overlay
parport
parport_pc
ppdev
psmouse
pstore_blk
pstore_zone
r8169
ramoops
rapl
rc_core
realtek
reed_solomon
rfcomm
sch_fq_codel
serio_raw
snd
snd_acp6x_pdm_dma
snd_compress
snd_ctl_led
snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core
snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep
snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_intel_sdw_acpi
snd_pci_acp3x
snd_pci_acp5x
snd_pci_acp6x
snd_pcm
snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_rawmidi
snd_rn_pci_acp3x
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event
snd_soc_acp6x_mach
snd_soc_core
snd_soc_dmic
snd_timer
soundcore
sparse_keymap
stp
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
thunderbolt
tls
ttm
typec
typec_ucsi
ucsi_acpi
usbhid
uvcvideo
video
videobuf2_common
videobuf2_memops
videobuf2_v4l2
videobuf2_vmalloc
videodev
wmi
wmi_bmof
x_tables
xfrm_algo
xfrm_user
xhci_pci
xhci_pci_renesas
xt_MASQUERADE
xt_addrtype
xt_conntrack


!!Sysfs Files
!!-----------

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/init_pin_configs:
0x04 0x185600f0

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/driver_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/init_verbs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/hints:

/sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/init_pin_configs:
0x03 0x185600f0
0x05 0x585600f0
0x07 0x585600f0
0x09 0x585600f0
0x0b 0x585600f0

/sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/driver_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/user_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/init_verbs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/hints:

/sys/class/sound/hwC2D0/init_pin_configs:
0x12 0x40000000
0x13 0x411111f0
0x14 0x90170110
0x16 0x411111f0
0x17 0x411111f0
0x18 0x411111f0
0x19 0x411111f0
0x1a 0x411111f0
0x1b 0x411111f0
0x1d 0x40400001
0x1e 0x411111f0
0x21 0x04211020

/sys/class/sound/hwC2D0/driver_pin_configs:
0x19 0x01a1913c
0x1b 0x01a1913d

/sys/class/sound/hwC2D0/user_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC2D0/init_verbs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC2D0/hints:


!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

ii  alsa-topology-conf                         1.2.5.1-2                               all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                              1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1                        all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.2.6-1ubuntu1                          amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating to kernel 6.0.11 fixes this for me.

See https://www.techrepublic.com/article/install-linux-kernel-ubuntu/ for how (but install mainline and then use mainline to install 6.0.11)